# Unable to use mocked data which is available in redux store for react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I was unable to mock the initial values in the redux store display them, for some reason. You can check the error messages in the console.
Note: I have attached the same replica of the problem in code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-react-testing-library-6r1m5

```
const setUpDOM = () =>
  renderWithRedux(<UsersList />, {
    initialState: {
      usersList: fakeData
    }
  });

test("loads and displays user list", async () => {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  const { getByText, getByTestId } = setUpDOM();

  const s = await wait(() => getByTestId("user_list_datata"));
  console.log(s, "-sadsad"); // Able to console the data once, it is throwing undefined later in re-renders
});
```